# minBound and maxBound return wrong number for Int

Tags: haskell

> A fixed-precision integer type with at least the range [-2^29 ..
>   2^29-1]. The exact range for a given implementation can be determined
>   by using minBound and maxBound from the Bounded class.

This came straight from hackage.haskell.org.

According to both hackage.haskell.org and learnyouahaskell.com, what I'm supposed to get is `-2147483648` for `minBound` and `2147483648` for `maxBound`.

When I actually run it myself, I get this result :

[image]

Apologies if this is a really stupid question. I'm new to Haskell and was testing around to see how things worked.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Int`s are only guaranteed to have *at least* that range.  `Int`s on your platform are 64 bits.  Compare with `2^63`.

Comment: Ohhhhh! That makes so much sense! Although, you should've answered that as an answer and not a comment so I can give you best answer. :P

Comment: Next time read twice the documentation before posting a question. Moreover do *not* use screenshots when you could simply copy & paste text in a code block. By using screenshots you just made the post useless to impaired readers (yes they exist; you should add a description to your images for this reason), moreover it would be impossible for an answerer to copy and paste the result you get. In other words: you are harming usability for most users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Int`s are only guaranteed to have *at least* that range.  `Int`s on your platform appear to be 64 bits.   Compare with `2^63`:

```
ghci> 2^63
9223372036854775808
```